# Collapse div on click of child element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, parent-child

I am trying to collapse parent div on click of child element like below

**HTML**

```
<div class="expand">
    <h3>expand this div</h3>
    <a href="#" class="collapse" style="display:none;">Collapse</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.expand{
    border:2px dotted green;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.expand').click(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({
        width:'300px',
        height:'300px'
    });
    $('.collapse').show();
});

 $('.collapse').on('click',function(){
     $('.expand').stop().animate({
         width: '300px',
         height:'50px'
     });
 });
```

It's not working, I've tried using `$(this).parent().animation()` too, but that also dosen't work.

What changes should be done here ?

[**LIVE FIDDLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nvR2S/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.collapse').on('click',function(e){
     e.stopPropagation()
     $(this).parent('.expand').stop().animate({
         width: '300px',
         height:'50px'
     });
     $(this).hide();
});
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/nvR2S/2/)

Your code didn't work because on click of the inner child `div` the parent `div` was also clicked. We had stopped that using the [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) and your code just works fine.

Also added the `$(this).hide()` to hide the `collapse` on click of it.

Comment: +1 Thanks, it worked great. some description with answer would help someone in future.

Comment: It's nice to see added explanation. It'll help someone for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$('.expand').on('click', '.collapse',function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 $(this).hide();
 $('.expand').stop().animate({
     width: '300px',
     height:'50px'
 });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Sdp4W/)

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because you click on the `.collapse` link bubbles up to the `.expand` div triggering back the expand functionality. You can prevent the bubbling by calling `event.stopPropagation();`

```
$('.collapse').on('click',function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     $('.expand').stop().animate({
         width: '300px',
         height:'50px'
     });
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nvR2S/1/